# Determine XML file based type to specify the corresponding handler

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, deserialization

I have a ScheduledJob which checks a configured folder every xx seconds for new XML files. As the content of each XML file differs, I need to determine which handler should be used deserialize the specific XML file and do some further processing.

As far as I know there is a easy war using JAXB to unmarshal / deserialize XML but to do so you need to specify the corresponding class of the XML file. In this case I need to choose the right handler based on the Class / POJO the XML file belongs to.

For example like the following:
The corresponding Handler handles the specific type / class of the XML file.

```
List<File> xmlFiles = Arrays.asList(xmlFilesDirectory.listFiles(((dir, name) -> {return name.toLowerCase().endsWith(".xml");})));

for(File xmlFile : xmlFiles)
{
    // Load XML 
    // decide which class / object to unmarshal to.


    switch (xmlClassType) {
        case TypeA:
            abstractXmlHandler = typeAXmlHandler;
            break;
        case TypeB:
            abstractXmlHandler = typeBXmlHandler;
            break;
        case TypeC:
            abstractXmlHandler = typeCXmlHandler;
            break;
        default:
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Unknown type");
    }

abstractXmlHandler.handle(xmlFile)

}
```

Comment: The easiest would be a filename convention. If that is not possible you can use a SAX or StAX parser to parse the first elements to determine the right handler.

Comment: Unfortunatly a file name convention is not possible... I'll have a look at SAX or StAX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but to do so you need to specify the corresponding class of the XML file

Not correct. You can create your JAXB context using context path, for instance:

```
JAXBContext.newInstance("com.acme.foo:com.acme:bar");
```

Context path is one or more package names separated by `:`.

With this method you don't need to specify exact class(es), you can specify all the possible packages at once.

Comment: If I would it do that way, how can I determine the "output object". So far the unmarshalling happens as following:
`Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
  MyClass myClass= (MyClass) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(xmlFile);`

In this example I have to specify the target class. If I add all classes using context path how do I know the target?

Comment: On the compile time you can't know the target. You will typically get an instance of `JAXBElement` which would contain value as well as its class. You can use those to select the handler.

Comment: Unfortunatly that does not work. `"my.package" doesnt contain ObjectFactory.class or jaxb.index`. Should say using spring and gradle. Searching this error leads to many solutions but none of them is working so far. Why must Java be so much more complicated than C#

Comment: @bananajoe This works, but you do need `ObjectFactory` or `jaxb.index`. `jaxb.index` is the simplest, just enumerate all the relevant classes from the package in there.

Comment: thats what I've already tried. I've placed a jaxb.index file besides my two test classes in the same package but I still get the same exception. Can currently not determine whats missing.

Comment: @bananajoe I suggest you ask another question then, providing a MCVE. This is known to work.

Comment: thats dumb but I found the solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36718724/9295125 - I had to place the jaxb.index file into the resource with the exact structure as my classes.

The great thing is now I have the possibilitie to do the following:
` Object o = jaxbContextUnmarshaller.unmarshal(xmlFile);`
and then I can get the specific type by `o.getClass`.

Comment: @bananajoe Careful. Use `JAXBIntrospector.getValue()` on what you've unmarshalled to get value. In some cases you get an instance of `JAXBElement` which wraps the actual value.